# calling bash script generates error on if statement and variable assignment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I'm trying to execute a very simple program (round numbers to lowest integer divisible by 15) but am getting an error:

```
$min = date +"%M";

if [ $min%15 != 0 ]
  then
    $min - $min%1
fi

echo $min;
```

I call it with `sh cache.sh`

I feel I've followed the syntax I've learned [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) but I'm getting `line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file` What have I got wrong here?

Comment: One of the things I think it's important to know when looking at bash samples is that *every single character* is significant. Especially the spaces. And the lack of spaces.

Answer (score 2):

That script is not valid bash syntax.  I would start by finding some working examples, and perhaps an entire tutorial. You might start with William Shotts' book, which is [available online](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_writing_shell_scripts.php).

Some notes about your attempt:

1. The `$` is used to request replacement of a variable<sup>1</sup> by its value. It is not a sigil that is part of the variable name, as it is in Perl or PHP.  So it is not used on the left-hand-side of an assignment.
2. The shell is primarily used to run other executables, and interprets everything through that lens.  If a command line looks like an invocation of another program, the shell will try to run that other program, rather than do anything shell-scripty.  Therefore, the command `min = date +"%M"` will cause the shell to look for a program named `min` and execute it with three command-line arguments: `=`, `date`, and `+%M`.
   In order for an assignment to be recognized as such, there cannot be any space around the `=`.
3. Without spaces, `min=date +"%M"` is still not right, however. The shell will just temporarily assign the literal string "date" to the variable `min` and then try to run a command called `+%M`.
   If a value has spaces in it, you need quotation marks around it<sup>2</sup>.
4. Even with quotes, however,`min="date +%M"` would assign to `min` the literal string "date +%M".  If you actually want to *run the command* `date +"%M"` and use its output as a value, then you have to request that using the command-substitution syntax, `$(...)`. Here our friend the dollar sign is again requesting replacement by a dynamic value, but the parentheses make it a different type of request; instead of a variable's value, the expression is replaced by the output of a command.
5. Because of the parsing issues noted above, the built-in arithmetic operations only work in certain contexts.  Two ways to create a valid arithmetic context are the `((`...`))` special forms and the `let` command.
6. Finally, even if your script were syntactically valid, it is semantically incorrect if your goal is to round down to the nearest multiple of 15. The remainder after dividing by 1 is always zero, so your script ends by attempting to subtract 0 from `min` - and does nothing with the result anyway, since there's no assignment back to `min`. If you want to round down, you have to actually subtract the remainder that you just tested. You could do it like this:

   ```
   min=$(date +%M)
   let rem=min%15
   if (( rem != 0 )); then
     let min-=rem
   fi
   echo $min
   ```

But you could also do it a bit more succinctly:

```
echo $(( min=$(date +%M), min-=min%15 ))
```

This works without an `if` because subtracting 0 is harmless.  The comma just lets us put two expressions inside a single set of `((...))`. The second expression `min-=min%15` is a modifying assignment - it means the same thing as `min=min-min%15`, but saves us one instance of typing out "min". Putting our friend the replacement-requesting `$` in front of `((`...`))` causes the whole expression to be replaced by its value, so that `echo` gets something to print out.  The value of a list of expressions is the value of the last expression, and the value of an assignment is the same as the value that was assigned, so the result that is `echo`ed is the same as the final value of `$min`: the closest multiple of 15 minutes after the hour.

<sup>1</sup> In shell terminology, variables are actually called "parameters".  Just something to bear in mind when reading documentation.

<sup>2</sup> You actually *don't* need quotation marks around the `%M` in your command for this reason. Everything in the shell is automatically a string; you don't need the quotes to make it one.  However, they don't hurt, and putting quotation marks around things is a good habit to have, since it keeps your code from being broken by unexpected special characters in input values.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really a lot of information. Your first code snippet produces the error " line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file". I don't really understand what's happening in the second example, but it does not return a value.

Comment: @thomas I just verified that both examples work for me by copying and pasting from here into my terminal window. I did make some edits, though, so please double-check.

Answer (score 0):

Your script has many syntax issues. In shell assignment is is

var='val'

instead of

$var='val'

Also there is no space around `=`

Your correct script can be:

```
min=$(date +"%M")

if (( min % 15 != 0 ))
then
    echo "not fully divisible by 15"
fi

echo $min
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the error: "line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `"

Comment: Make sure you execute it as `bash ./script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you converted this from some other language.  Here's a working bash version.

```
#!/bin/bash
min=$(date +"%M")

if [ $(($min % 15)) != 0 ] ; then
    min=$(( min - min % 1 ))
fi

echo $min;
```

local output:

```
~/tmp › sh ./test.sh
34
```

Comment: Yeah, totally coming from a ternary in PHP heheh. I get the error " syntax error: unexpected end of file" with your snippet. Any ideas what that could be? Thanks!

Comment: I ran it here without a problem.  What OS/shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
 min=`date +"%M"`;

 if [ $min%15 != 0 ]

 then

 min=$((min - min%1))

 fi

 echo $min;
```